# Wave equation solution: jumping rope

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

I have a problem of PDE of jumping rope

$\tau \hspace{0.1 cm}u_{tt} = \rho \hspace{0.1 cm} u_{xx}$ and the boundary conditions are forced sine waves as $$ u(0, t) = sin(\omega t) \text{ and } u(1,t) = sin(\omega t) $$, I have solved it by first splitting it to have homogeneous boundary conditions and then solved by eigenfunction expansion, but the problem is that the question asks about why the density is likely to be fixed.
this is the question[question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dyFe.png)

Comment: Can you change the density of your jumping rope (I can't on mine:) You can adjust the tension by stretching it, and the frequency $\omega$ can be adjusted by skipping faster.

Comment: Good answer, but the question, I think, requires to get that from the eigenfunction expansion coefficients.

Comment: No, part (d) is a physical interpretation question. The density and tension are material parameters; you cannot determine whether they are adjustable by solving the PDE. This depends on the physical interpretation of the wave equation. In this case, you are unlikely to be able to adjust the density of a jump rope, without say cutting it in half lengthwise. However, if you are the manufacturer of the rope, the density could be a design parameter you could adjust by using different materials of different thickness.

Comment: Part (e) certainly requires solving the wave equation using a Fourier expansion.